# Spring's @WebMvcTest doesn't work with Java 8 types

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-8

In the spring boot app I have a rest controller which takes a payload containing a Java 8 type `LocalDate`. 
Also I have this library plugged in:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Controller works fine when called however a `@WebMvcTest` integration test fails on that field with 400 HTTP code and this exception:

```
Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException
```

Date in the production call and the test call is passed as:

```
"date":"2017-03-21"
```

if that matters.

Is there a way to make `@WebMvcTest` work with Java8 types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Eugene's hint added the following bean configuration to the test configuration:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    return builder.modules(new JavaTimeModule()).build();
}
```

That solved the problem.

**EDIT:**
Works fine with a simpler config (Spring Boot + jackson-datatype-jsr310 library in the classpath):

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should register whatever converter you have with `MockMvcBuilders`, for example:

```
MockMvcBuilders
        .standaloneSetup(controller)
        .setMessageConverters(converter) // register..
        .build();
```

Or simply (I do it like this) have a `@Bean` that returns the already configured `ObjectMapper` (with `ObjectMapper#registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())`) and return that.  This `@Configuration` should be used within your test.

Comment: JSR310Module() is deprecated, one should use JavaTimeModule()

Answer (score 0):

As for java.time.LocalDate you can directly parse/format your LocalDate into a String which is then parsed back into a LocalDate by your RestControllerMethod:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/datecontroller/")
public class YourDateController{

@GetMapping(value = "myDateMethod/" + "date")
public void yourDateMethod(@PathVariable("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") final LocalDate date) {
// ... your code ...
    }
}
```